Change in k-points sampling method during different DFT steps
Does using different k-point sampling methods at different steps of DFT calculations, e.g. Monkhorst-Pack in SCF and Gamma in non-SCF step (leaving others unchanged) lead to inaccurate results particularly related to band energies or its derivatives(bandstructure)?
